# In the effective JCL, with what value will the symbolic parameter &DEPT be replaced by?

Tags: jcl

In the effective JCL, with what value will the symbolic parameter &DEPT be replaced by? 
Procedure

```
//ABC9999 PROC DEPT=’A’
//ABC9090 EXEC PGM=ABC9090
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=&DEPT
//ABCREAD DD DSNAME=AAX1.MASTER.FILE,DISP=SHR
```

Invoking JCL

```
//AAX1BN JOB (12345),'CANDIDATE TEST',NOTIFY=CANDIDATE,
//MSGCLASS=X,MSGLEVEL=(1,1)
//SET DEPT=’*’
//STEPX1 EXEC ABC9999
```

Answer (score 0):

As currently supplied, nothing.  After you fix the syntax errors, &DEPT will be replaced with an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Currently DEPT will be A because it initialized to that in the proc

//ABC9999 PROC **DEPT=’A’**

You need to either code

```
//AAX1BN JOB (12345),'CANDIDATE TEST',NOTIFY=CANDIDATE,
//MSGCLASS=X,MSGLEVEL=(1,1)
//*
//STEPX1 EXEC ABC9999,DEPT=’*’
```

or remove the initialize (remove DEPT=’A’) from the proc:

```
//ABC9999 PROC 
//ABC9090 EXEC PGM=ABC9090
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=&DEPT
//ABCREAD DD DSNAME=AAX1.MASTER.FILE,DISP=SHR
```

Comment: I believe the SET statement will accomplish the same as specifying the value on the EXEC statement (making DEPT=*).

Comment: If you have mainframe handy try it, I do not have access to a mainframe any more; My Feeling is  you do have to actually override proc parameters. The